# Need help figuring out how to update state from the values of a list gotten by an async function in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have code that when entering a screen with useFocusEffect, fetches an array of payments, and for each payment within that list there is another async function which is called that retrieves data about that payment including the value of it. I am trying to sum up the values of the payments in this list and set a state variable too it, but according to my understanding they are all happening at the same time and the state value is updated to just the value of the last payment that is read from the array. What would be the best way to make it so that my state updates to the sum of the values of the payments? I've tried various combinations of solutions with storing values in local variables and setting the state to the local variable in the end but nothing seems to work. Below is the code to help visualize what I am doing.

```
fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID).then((payments) => {
            payments.forEach(pid => {
                  fetchPayment(pid).then(payment => {
                    setAmountReceive(payment.value + amountReceive);
                    console.log(amountReceive, payment.value);
                    if (payment.sender == username) {
                        setAmountReceive(amountReceive + payment.value);           
                    }
                })
            }); 
        });
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: What does `fetchPaymentsInChat` and `fetchPayment` return? Please share their code as well so we can see what's the Firebase related part here.  Can you `console.log(payments)` and share the output? You should update state only once and not in every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it comes down to improper Promise chaining and a misunderstanding of how `setState` callbacks work.

```
fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID)
  .then((payments) => {
    payments.forEach(pid => {
      fetchPayment(pid) // <- floating Promises in loop
        .then(payment => {
          setAmountReceive(payment.value + amountReceive);  // <- sums early?
          console.log(amountReceive, payment.value); // improperly attempts to use new amountReceive value
          if (payment.sender == username) {
            setAmountReceive(amountReceive + payment.value); // <- attempts to sum again?
          }
        })
    }); 
});
```

When using a `setState` callback from a `useState` call, it will set the value for the **next** render of your component - it doesn't update the value for the current render. There are resources online that explain how `useState` works, but for the purpose of showing how it's not updated immediately, we can look at this pseudo-code:

```
const useState = (initValue) => {
  useState._value = "_value" in useState ? useState._value : initValue;
  return [useState._value, (v) => useState._value = v]
}

let [value, setValue] = useState(0);
console.log(value); // => 0
setValue(1);
console.log(value); // => 0  [but _value is now 1]
setValue(value + 1);
console.log(value); // => 0  [but _value is still 1 (0 + 1)]
// --- start next loop --- (imagine we've gone back to useState(0) line)
[value, setValue] = useState(0);
console.log(value); // => 1
setValue(1);
console.log(value); // => 1  [but _value is still 1]
setValue(value + 1);
console.log(value); // => 1  [but _value is now 2 (1 + 1)]
// --- start next loop --- (imagine we've gone back to useState(0) line again)
[value, setValue] = useState(0);
console.log(value); // => 2
setValue(1);
console.log(value); // => 2  [but _value is now back to 1]
setValue(value + 1);
console.log(value); // => 2  [but _value is now 3 (2 + 1)]
// ...
```

As can be seen from the above lines, summing against the current value doesn't work as expected. While a `setState` callback can be fed a function another callback to update the value that looks like `(oldValue) => newValue`, we don't need to use it here.

This is because both issues can be solved by fixing up the Promise chains using `Promise.all` combined with `Array#map` and `Array#reduce`.

```
fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID)
  .then((paymentIDs) => {
    return Promise.all(
      paymentIDs.map(pid => {
        return fetchPayment(pid)
          .then(paymentDetails => paymentDetails.value)
      })
    );
  })
  .then((paymentValues) => {
    const paymentSum = paymentValues.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
    setAmountReceive(paymentSum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    /* don't forget error handling */
  })
```

If the intention is to only sum the payments where the sender is `username`, instead use:

```
fetchPaymentsInChat(props.threadID)
  .then((paymentIDs) => {
    return Promise.all(
      paymentIDs.map(pid => {
        return fetchPayment(pid)
          .then(paymentDetails => {
            return paymentDetails.sender === username ? paymentDetails.value : 0
          })
      })
    );
  })
  .then((paymentValues) => {
    const paymentSum = paymentValues.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
    setAmountReceive(paymentSum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    /* don't forget error handling */
  })
```